# Perfect square test for polynomial $(x^2+p)^2 + p^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $f_p(x) = (x^2+p)^2 + p^2$, $p \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \ge 1$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Prove that $f_p(x)$ is never a perfect square, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\forall p \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \ge 1$.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: All I tried is to generate some values using a computer, and the statement seems to be true.

Comment: To me it looks like the pythagorean triples.

Comment: To be clear, you mean that $f_p(x)$ is never a square for _all_ $x$, correct?  Or do you mean that there's no pair $(p,x)$ for which it's a square?

Comment: The first one. $f_p(x)$ is never a square for all $x$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki And for every $p$! I can't see the difference between the two statements!

Comment: @Maffred Otherwise we have cases like $f_3(1)=4^2+3^2=5^2$. Admittedly the formulation of the question could make it clearer. Hence Steven's question.

Comment: If it means it can't be a square for all $x$ for a fixed $p$,  just take $x=0, f_p(0)=2p^2$. It's not a perfect square for $p \ge 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=0, f_p(0)=2p^2$, it's not a perfect square for all $p \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
f_p(p)=(p^2+p)^2+p^2=p^2[(p+1)^2+1].
$$
This is a perfect square, iff $m=(p+1)^2+1$ is a square. But $m-1=(p+1)^2$ is a perfect square. The only two consecutive perfect squares are $0$ and $1$. But $p=-1$ was excluded.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that there is a relationship with solutions of Pell's equation, but it must still be written more clearly and in a more general way.

Solutions of the equation: $X^2+(X\pm{a})^2=Y^2$

Defined solutions of Pell's equation: $p^2-2s^2=\pm{a}$

And the solutions are of the form:

$X=2s(s+p)$

$Y=2s(s+p)+p^2$

These numbers can be different characters.

I almost forgot. If we know what the solution of Pell's equation $p^2-2s^2=a$

$s_{2}=2p+3s$

$p_{2}=3p+4s$

For such equations.

$$(X^2+p)^2+p^2=Y^2$$

Solution write.

$$X=k^2-2t^2$$

$$p=(k^2+2t^2)(2t^2-(k-2t)^2)$$

$$Y=k^4-4k^3t+12k^2t^2-8kt^3+4t^4$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix $p$.

As soon as $x> \sqrt{\frac{p^2-2p-1}{2}}$, $f_p(x)$ is strictly between two consecutives perfect squares: $$ (x^2+p)^2 <f_p(x)< (x^2 + p +1)^2$$

thus it can't be a perfect square unless for a finite number of $x$.